# My bluetooth is not working, it is not turning ON, i ran sudo apt update and upgrade and it shows the following error. How can I fix this?UBUNTU 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, blueman

I tried turning on the Bluetooth, but it is not working. I tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and it shows the following error

[image: bluetooth]

Comment: Are the folders `/var/lib/bluetooth`, `/var/tmp` and `/etc/bluetooth` intact? What if you try `sudo apt reinstall bluez` and reboot?